# What can be said about pairs of matrices P,Q that satisfies $(P^{-1})^T \circ P = (Q^{-1})^T \circ Q$ ?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Let $P,Q$ be $n$ by $n$ invertible matrices. Suppose further that $P$ and $Q$ satisfies the following equation :

$$(P^{-1})^T \circ P = (Q^{-1})^T \circ Q$$

where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard matrix product, which is simply the entrywise product.

Then what can be said about $P$ and $Q$? More precisely, I want to know if there are additional relations between $P$ and $Q$. For example, one can show that the condition $(P^{-1})^T \circ P = (Q^{-1})^T \circ Q$ implies

$$tr(P^{-1}DPE) = tr(Q^{-1}DQE)$$ for all diagonal matrices $D$ and $E$.

References in the litterature about matrices of the form $(P^{-1})^T \circ P$ would help too.
Thank you,
Malik

Comment: I guess $P^{-1}$ is the ordinary matrix inverse?

Matrix algebras which are also closed under the Hadamard product are called association schemes. There is a monograph by Bannai-Ito on them 
(a special case is given by algebras generated by strongly regular graphs, there is also a monograph on them by Brouwer, .... which contains chapters on association schemes). Perhaps you should also have a look at Terwilliger pairs which might be relevant for your problem. 

Comment: Yes, P^{-1} is the ordinary matrix inverse, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the references, I'll take a look at them.

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63027/matrices-that-are-hadamard-products-of-x-and-x-t. I'd start from the book suggested in the answer, Horn and Johnson's *Topics in Matrix Analysis* (not to be confused with *Matrix Analysis* by the same authors).

Comment: Just terminology. The matrix $P^{-T}\circ P$ is the *gain array* matrix associated with $P$. It was studied by C. R. Johnson & H. Shapiro.

Answer (score 3):

You might already know this, but I thought it was interesting:

The all-ones vector is always an eigenvector of $(P^{-1})^\mathrm{T}\circ P$ with eigenvalue $1$.  To see this, note that the $i$th entry of $((P^{-1})^\mathrm{T}\circ P)\mathbf{1}=(P\circ (P^{-1})^\mathrm{T})\mathbf{1}$ is precisely the $(i,i)$th entry of $PP^{-1}=I$ by the definition of matrix multiplication.

**UPDATE:** In hindsight, this is a special case of Theorem DMHP from [Dietrich Burde's link](http://linear.ups.edu/jsmath/0200/fcla-jsmath-2.00li101.html).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if $D, E$ are diagonal and $Q=EPD$, then $(P,Q)$ is such a pair. A natural question is whether every pair such that $P^{-T}\circ P=Q^{-T}\circ Q$ is of the form above. But even this is false, because if $P$ is triangular, then $P^{-T}\circ P=I_n$.

I take the occasion to mention an open question: define $\Phi(P):=P^{-T}\circ P$ (the *gain array*). What are the matrices $P$ such that $\Phi^{(k)}(P)\rightarrow I_n$ as $k\rightarrow+\infty$ ? According to Johnson & Shapiro, this is true at least for

- Strictly diagonally dominant matrices
- Symmetric positive definite matrices

On the contrary, $\Phi$ has fixed points, for instance the mean $\frac12(P+Q)$ of two permutation matrices. See Exercises 335, 336, 342, 343 of my blog about [Exercises on matrix analysis.](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/exobis.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Also the following can be said about $P$ and $Q$. Your relation implies
that the two matrices $PDP^{-1}$ and $QDQ^{-1}$ have the same diagonal elements for any diagonal matrix $D$. For $n=2$ this is a necessary and suffcient condition for the equality 
$(P^{-1})^T\circ P=(Q^{-1})^T\circ P$.

Here is a Reference: http://linear.ups.edu/jsmath/0200/fcla-jsmath-2.00li101.html